# How do you break an array in to little arrays of a fixed size? (in C)

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to do an exercise in Hacker Rank but found that my code(which is below) is too linear. To make it better I want to know if it is possible to break an array in to little arrays of a fixed size to complete this exercise.

[The Exersise on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/ioi-sri-lanka-2015/challenges/number-grid/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int N, M, Y, X;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &M, &Y, &X);

int max = 0;
int total = 0;
int data[N][M];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&(data[i][j]));    
    }
}


for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        total = 0;

            for(int l = 0; (l < Y) && (i + Y) <= N; l++)
            {

                for(int k = 0; (k < X) && (j + X <= M); k++)
                {
                    total += data[i+l][j+k];
                }

                if(total > max)
                    max = total;                       
        } 
    }  
}   

printf("%d",max);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While "breaking" it into pieces implies that we'd be moving things around in memory, you may be able to "view" the array in such a way that is equivalent.

In a very real sense the name of the array is simply a pointer to the first element.  When you dereference an element of the array an array mapping function is used to perform pointer arithmetic so that the correct element can be located.  This is necessary because C arrays do not natively have any pointer information within them to identify elements.

The nature of how arrays are stored, however, can be leveraged by you to treat the data as arbitrary arrays of whatever size you'd like.  For example, if we had:

`int integers[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`

you could view this as a single array:

`for(i=0;i!=10;i++){ printf("%d\n", integers[i]); }`

But starting with the above array you could also do this:

```
int *iArray1, *iArray2;
iArray1 = integers;
iArray2 = integers + (5 * sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i!=5;i++){ printf("%d - %d\n", iArray1[i], iArray2[i]);}
```

In this way we are choosing to *view* the data as two 5 term arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the linear solution. The main problem is in your algorithm complexity. As it's written it's O(N^4). Also I think your solution is not correct since:

> The ceulluar tower can cover a regtangular area of Y rows and X columns.

It does not mean exactly Y rows and X columns IMHO you could find a solution where the are dimension is less than X, Y.

The problems like that are solvable in reasonable time using dynamic programming. Try to optimize your program using dynamic programming to O(N^2).